# hibernate: deleting entity in a one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`spindledb`.`section`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ftoru9cp83n512p9is8x3vo53` FOREIGN KEY (`scenario_id`) REFERENCES `scenario` (`scenario_id`))
```

Here are my classes:

Scenario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scenario")
public class Scenario {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "scenario_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
private String title;

@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate creationDate;

@ManyToOne
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
private User user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario", orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Set<Plot> plotList = new HashSet<Plot>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario", orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Set<Character> characterList = new HashSet<Character>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OrderBy("sequence ASC")
private Set<Section> sectionList = new HashSet<Section>();
```

Section:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "section")
public class Section {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "section_id")
private int id;

@Size(min = 4, max = 50)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "type")
private String type = SectionType.TEXT.getSectionType();

@Column(name = "visibility")
private boolean visibility;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "sequence")
private int sequence;

@ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name = "scenario_id", nullable = false)
private Scenario scenario;
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-{id}-scenario" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteScenario(@PathVariable int id) {

    scenarioService.deleteScenarioById(id);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Scenario service:

```
@Service("scenarioService")
@Transactional
public class ScenarioServiceImpl implements ScenarioService {

@Autowired
private ScenarioDao dao;

@Override
public Scenario findById(int id) {
    return dao.findById(id);
}

@Override
public void saveScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    dao.saveScenario(scenario);

}

public void updateScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    Scenario entity = dao.findById(scenario.getId());
    if(entity!=null){
        entity.setTitle(scenario.getTitle());
        entity.setCreationDate(scenario.getCreationDate());            
    }
}

@Override
public void deleteScenarioById(int id) {
    dao.deleteScenarioById(id);

}
```

Dao

```
@Repository("scenarioDao")
public class ScenarioDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Scenario> implements ScenarioDao {

@Override
public Scenario findById(int id) {
    return getByKey(id);
}

@Override
public void saveScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    persist(scenario);

}

@Override
public void deleteScenarioById(int id) {

    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from scenario where id = :id");
    query.setString("id", ""+id);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

I understand that the problem is that there may be a Section that can not exist without scenario. Right now however section table in database is empty and I still can't remove Scenario. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

use `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` with all `@ManyToOne` relations in `class Scenario` because if you are going to delete any Scenario from database it must not be referenced any where in data base.

the other way to delete is.

```
Serializable id = new Long(1); //your id
Object persistentInstance = session.load(Scenario.class, id);
if (persistentInstance != null) {
    session.delete(persistentInstance);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help

Comment: Deleting an entity via Query would bypass any Cascade setting. So that really wouldn't help.

Comment: Use following technique to delete  defined 
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore

Serializable id = new Long(1); //your id
Object persistentInstance = session.load(Scenario.class, id);
if (persistentInstance != null) {
    session.delete(persistentInstance);
}

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an entity via `Query` would bypass any Cascade settings you put via annotation.

I would suggest find the entity first by id, then delete the entity object:

```
Object scenario = session.load(Scenario.class, id);
if (scenario != null) {
    session.delete(scenario);
}
```